# Feeding JSON results from MongoDB into Django Template view doesn't display dictionary values

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I'm returning a record set from MongoDB, parsing this as JSON and pushing this into a view and attempting to access dictionary values of each record in a template. I can print the records (as an individual record), but I cannot access the structure of each record as a dictionary. How can I get at the values?

```
def index(request): 
    results = settings.vali_collection.find({'index': []  })
    json_docs = [json.dumps(doc, default=json_util.default) for doc in results]
    return render(request, 'db.html', {'results': json_docs[0:3]})
```

In my template:

```
{% for result in results %}
    {{ result.name}}
    {{ result.items.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

My JSON looks like:

```
{"name": "Travel & Leisure", .., ..}
```

I can print the records in my template with `{{record}}`, but how do I get at the record as a dictionary? What I have above in the template doesn't work and returns nothing. But when I use:

```
{% for result in results %}
  {{ result}}
{% endfor %}
```

I can get the records printed out to screen in JSON format. If I print out json_docs I get the following:

```
['{"name": "random", "sector": "random"}',  {"name": "random", "sector": "random"}', {"name": "random", "sector": "random"}']
```

Comment: What  `results = settings.vali_collection.find({'index': []  })` returns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the json is a dictionary itself, you need to have nested loops. Something like the following:

```
   {%for i in gme%}

       {%for l, k in i.items%}
           <p>  {{l}}  {{k}} </p>
       {%endfor%}

   {%endfor%}
```

`gme` looks like this:
`gme = [{"sdfje": 'sdfs',"sdfds": "sdf"},...]`

The output is:

```
 sdfje sdfs

sdfds sdf
```

Use `json.loads(...)` instead of `json.dumps`.

```
 json.dumps(obj, skipkeys=False, ensure_ascii=True, check_circular=True, allow_nan=True, cls=None, indent=None, separators=None, encoding="utf-8", default=None, sort_keys=False, **kw)

    Serialize obj to a JSON formatted str 

 json.loads(s[, encoding[, cls[, object_hook[, parse_float[, parse_int[, parse_constant[, object_pairs_hook[, **kw]]]]]]]])

    Deserialize s (a str or unicode instance containing a JSON document) to a Python object using this conversion table.
```

What you are doing is serializing python dictionary to `JSON formatted str`, so you get string instead of dictionary.

You need to deserialize and for that, you need `json.loads`

If you can't use `json.loads`, as you said in comments section, then the `results` variable is not a `json string`. Maybe it is what you are looking for? Try to debug and see what is inside `results`

Comment: Thanks but this was one of the first things that I tried. Somehow the template doesn't see the results as a dictionary - hence I cannot print out the keys.

Comment: @Navonod Can you debug or print the content of `json_docs` just before the return statement?

Comment: I get as I would expect a list of dictionaries

Comment: @Navonod I just checked your printed `json_docs`. It is not list of dictionaries. `'{"name": "random", "sector": "random"}'` is not a dictionary but a string.

Comment: @Navonod Also what you provided is not even list of strings. It has invalid syntax. Are you sure it is the correct printed message?

Comment: @Navonod Try using `json.loads(...)` instead of `json.dumps`

Comment: I tried using loads, but I get: expected string or buffer

Comment: @Navonod Then `settings.vali_collection.find({'index': []  })` returns a python object, not a json string. Try to print and see what it is. Most probably, you are getting list of dictionaries, so you don't need to use `json`

Comment: for some reason it works, I did it as you suggest without json encoding.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [`PyMongo 2.8`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/) [`find`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find) returns a [`Cursor`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html?highlight=cursor#module-pymongo.cursor) that can be sliced. This should work:

```
db.test.find()[20:25]
```

And this should also work:

```
result = db.test.find()
...
sliced_result = result[20:25]
```

You don't need to transform the result to JSON, you can transform the `Cursor` to a `list` and pass that directly to the template, like that:

```
def index(request): 
    results = settings.vali_collection.find({'index': []})[:3]

    return render(request, 'db.html', {'results': list(results)})
```

You need to use `list(results)` to force the `Cursor` to execute the query. In your template you'll have a list of `dicts`, so this should work:

```
{% for result in results %}
    {{ result.name }}
    {{ result.items.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

`result` should be a `dict`. The only problem I see is that [`items`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#for) is a template function in Django, this might confuse people that are reading your template, and would prevent you from doing something like this:

```
{% for result in results %}
    {% for attr_name, value in result.items %}
        {{ attr_name }}: {{ value }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The inner `for` would show every attribute, and their value, of a document in your MongoDB collection.

If you're using an older version of `PyMongo` that doesn't allow slicing, you may need to do something like this:

```
def index(request): 
    results = settings.vali_collection.find({'index': []}).limit(3)

    return render(request, 'db.html', {'results': list(results)})
```

[`limit`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html?highlight=limit#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.limit) limits the number of results returned by the `Cursor`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `result` in the template isn't what you think it is.  Let's examine as follows:

In function `index(request)`:

- `results = settings.vali_collection.find({'index': []  })` returns a list of dictionary-like objects.
- `json_docs = [json.dumps(doc, default=json_util.default) for doc in results]` returns a list of JSON **strings** (not dictionaries).

So later on when you iterate through the sublist `json_docs[0:3]`, you are just iterating through a list of strings which is why you cannot reference the `.name` and `.items` properties.

It looks like what you actually want is a `dict()` like object for each `result` in your template.  To do this, avoid dumping the dictionaries into JSON.

So instead of:

```
# WRONG:
json_docs = [json.dumps(doc, default=json_util.default) for doc in results]       
return render(request, 'db.html', {'results': json_docs[0:3]})
# /WRONG
```

...just pass the result in directly:

```
 results = settings.vali_collection.find({'index': []  })
 results = list(results)  # This may or may not be necessary, depending on what mongo client you're using
 return render(request, 'db.html', {'results' : results[:3])
```

Then in your template, when you iterate through `results`, each `result` should be a dictionary-like object which you can use `result.name` or `result.items` on.

BTW, the `result.items.name` reference in your code looks a bit weird to me (like it would return an error), but it's hard for me to debug without knowing what each `record` looks like.

Answer (score -1):

Change your view like this

```
def index(request): 
    results = settings.vali_collection.find({'index': []  })

    return render(request, 'db.html', json.dumps({"results":results[0:3]}))
```

You can now use your for loop to render

Comment: This doesn't work - results in: cannot set options after executing query

Comment: @Navonod which MongoDB library are you using? In PyMongo 2.8 this should work.